# Send Javascript Vairable To C# MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I need to send a JavaScript variable to a certain C# controller in MVC when a link is clicked. I don't want to do it with Jquery. I need to do it with JavaScript.

Here is The Code Of The Controller:

```
 **[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult saveuser(int id, string propertyName, string value)
        {
            var status = false;
            var message = "";
            //Update data to database 

            using (PaediatricDBEntities db = new PaediatricDBEntities())
            {
                var user = db.ShiftTypes.Find(id);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(user).Property(propertyName).CurrentValue = value;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Error!";
                }
            }
            var response = new { value = value, status = status, message = message };
            JObject o = JObject.FromObject(response);
            return Content(o.ToString());
        }**
```

I need to send 3 parameters to this controller via javascript, first is the id of the element, second is the property name of the element, 3rd is the value of the element.Thanks,

Comment: You say you don't want to use jQuery but you tagged this post with AJAX, which is a part of jQuery. Also, what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Plenty of tutorials out there that demonstrate the basics.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code.

Comment: I have added the relevant code to the post. Thanks,

Comment: We need to see your Controller, are you using the header? body? query string?  We have no idea what the server expects.

Comment: I have added the code of the function in the controller.Thanks,

Comment: You are using a query string so `$.ajax({ method: 'POST', url: '/Sample/SaveUser?id=' + id + '&propertyName=' + propertyName + '&value=' + value, success: function(response) { }});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do here is to call an endpoint with plain javascript?

This will do the job for you:

```
function callYourController(id, propertyName, value) {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           console.log(this.responseText);
       }
   };
   xhttp.open("POST", "www.google.com?id=" + id + "&propertyName=" + propertyName + "&value=" + value, true);
   xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is missing how to send three parameters to the controller.

Comment: @AhmedElassar I added parameters with the syntax to use the query string based on Nikola's answer.  No reason to add another answer to do in essence what he has provided.

Comment: Its not working yet, would you please provide the url of the controller, if the name of the controller is ShiftTypes and The Action Result is saveuser. How to call it instead of google.com

Comment: Then you would do `/ShiftTypes/SaveUser?id=8&propertyName=name&value=value'` . you may want to try to understand the fundamentals a bit more, you'll get better help on SO.

Comment: here is the function and its not working,      function callYourController(id, propertyName, value) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        console.log(this.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "/ShiftTypes/saveuser?id=8&propertyName=SFY_Name&value=testvalue", true);
           
                xhttp.send();
            }

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked finally, LOL!